# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the CallableStatement object is closed

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jdbc

The code below generates this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the CallableStatement object is closed.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsCallableStatement.checkOpen(JtdsCallableStatement.java:120)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.getConnection(JtdsStatement.java:1207)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.getConnection(JtdsResultSet.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.close(JtdsResultSet.java:470)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.close(DelegatingResultSet.java:152)
    at
```

This code below sometimes generates the error above, but sometimes does not:

```
   private void doRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String someString;
        try {
            this.connectDB();
            stmt = this.conn.prepareCall("{call sp_SomeSP1(?)}");
            stmt.setLong(1, someFunc());

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getInt(1)==someOtherFunc()) {
                    someString = rs.getString(2);
                    break;
                }
            }

            stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_someSP(?, ?)}");
            stmt.setLong(1, someFunc());
            stmt.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(getFrom().getTime()));

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                lastUpdated = rs.getTimestamp("LastUpdated");
            }

            request.setAttribute("lastUpdated", lastUpdated);

            LOGGER.debug("Forwarding to view...");
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SomeJSP.jsp").forward(this.request, this.response);

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Database connection lookup failed", e);
            sendError("Server Error");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Query failed", e);
            sendError("Server Error");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            LOGGER.error("View failed", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs!=null) rs.close(); 
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Result set closing failed", e);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Result set closing failed", e);
            }
            try {
                if (stmt!=null) stmt.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Statement closing failed", e);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Statement closing failed", e);
            }
            try {
                this.closeDB();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Database connection closing failed", e);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Database connection closing failed", e);
            }
        }
```

What this means is that `doRequest()` most of the time works properly, but sometimes we get **HTTP error 500**, and if we check tomcat logs we see:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the CallableStatement object is closed.
```

Comment: Please *verify* the parameter *index*.

Comment: Huh, why are you catching NPEs?

Comment: You're not closing the first statement and result set you get in this routine.

Comment: A statement close should close the resultset, and calling close on a closed resultset should be a no-op (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close())); looks like a bug in JTDS to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing this error message `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.close` in the stack trace, it looks like **you are getting error while closing the resultset**.

I would advice you to change your resultset check if condition to check whether result set is still open before closing it as:

```
    if (rs!=null && ! rs.isClosed()){
        //resultset is there and not in closed state
        rs.close(); 
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like the best analysis or fix, but question is why sometimes we don't get this error when we access the web app?

Comment: And after a while after some refresh, it throws the error, can you explain that scenario

Comment: @xybrek I suspect some concurrency issues where resultset is getting closed by a different processing thread. Try using concurrency attributes in prepare call methods as: `stmt = con.prepareCall("{call sp_someSP(?, ?)}", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,                                     ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);`

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be using a member variable with a Servlet (the `conn` variable).  however, Servlets can normally be called by multiple threads simultaneously.  how are you ensuring that multiple threads are not accidentally using/closing the same Connection?

Answer (score 1):

```
stmt.setLong(1, someFunc());
stmt.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(getFrom().getTime()));
```

It will be

```
stmt.setLong(1, someFunc());
stmt.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(getFrom().getTime()));
```